# How to get facebook app to work on both example.com and www.example.com?

Tags: facebook

Right now, if I set my facebook application url to: http://www.example.com, then all requests from http://example.com don't work. If I set the url to just http://example.com from within facebook, then all requests from http://www.example.com don't work.

How can I fix this so it'll work in both places?

Comment: It should work with www.example.com as the website url and example.com in your 'app domains', no?

Comment: @Igy Yes, that was it, the app domain wasn't set, setting it fixed it. Post as answer if you like and I'll accept.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Comment: Voted to merge with the 'standard' 191 error question instead, it's the same fix usually

Comment: @Igy That error is obsolete since I didn't get this error from them. So IMO this question should have its own answer to help people who have this problem in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting an app domain in facebook app settings fixed this issue.